# Orientation change doesn't work in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to check the work of orientation change **in angular** but it doesn't work.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngTouch','matchmedia-ng']);

function checkOrientation($scope){
    if($scope.landscape){
        $scope.isLandscape="landscape";
        alert($scope.isLandscape);
    }
    else{
        $scope.isLandscape="portrait";
        alert($scope.isLandscape);
    }
}

myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$window','matchmedia',
    function($scope, $window, matchmedia) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
        alert("submitted!");
    }
    $scope.desktop = matchmedia.isDesktop();
    $scope.tablet =matchmedia.isTablet();
    $scope.phone = matchmedia.isPhone();
    $scope.landscape = matchmedia.isLandscape();

        if($scope.desktop){
            alert("desktop");
        }
        else if($scope.tablet){
            alert("tablet");
        }
        else if($scope.phone){
            $scope.isDevice = 'phone';
        }

        checkOrientation($scope);

        /*screen.bind('orientationchange', function () {
            $route.reload();
        });*/
        angular.element($window).bind('orientationchange', function ($scope) {
            checkOrientation($scope);
        });
}]);
```

I have tried also an option of $route.reload() but it also doesn't work. It works but not when i change orientation.

Answer (score 0):

In checkOrientation you can just look at the values of the following to see what orientation you're in:

```
$window.screen.orientation.type
```